# GORM GIN Update Query Results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am building a Book API in Golang using Gin and GORM. I have successfully implemented the Create, get and delete parts of the API but the Update is resulting in 500 Internal Server Error. I am trying to for a Update functionality which only updates the specific tags provided in the body(example given below). Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

**GO Logs**

```
[31m2022/05/09 14:08:00 [Recovery] 2022/05/09 - 14:08:00 panic recovered:
PATCH /books/2 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Origin: chrome-extension://ihgpcfpkpmdcghlnaofdmjkoemnlijdi
Sec-Ch-Ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36


reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetString on uint Value
C:/Program Files/Go/src/reflect/value.go:221 (0xc7bb04)
        flag.mustBe: panic(&ValueError{methodName(), f.kind()})
C:/Program Files/Go/src/reflect/value.go:1747 (0xc7ba3e)
        Value.SetString: v.mustBe(String)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/schema/field.go:771 (0x10defb7)
        (*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func11: field.ReflectValueOf(ctx, value).SetString(data)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/callbacks/update.go:144 (0x115b68e)
        ConvertToAssignments.func2: field.Set(stmt.Context, stmt.ReflectValue, value)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/callbacks/update.go:275 (0x11534f9)
        ConvertToAssignments: assignValue(field, value)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/callbacks/update.go:73 (0x115ac9e)
        Update.func1: if set := ConvertToAssignments(db.Statement); len(set) != 0 {
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/callbacks.go:130 (0x10ebe14)
        (*processor).Execute: f(db)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/finisher_api.go:372 (0x10f4e8d)
        (*DB).Updates: return tx.callbacks.Update().Execute(tx)
C:/New folder/golang/github.com/shashank-kakarla/BookAPI/controllers/books.go:101 (0x1167007)
        UpdateBook: models.DB.Model(&book).Updates(input)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x10917e1)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/recovery.go:99 (0x10917c7)
        CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x10908c6)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/logger.go:241 (0x1090885)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/context.go:168 (0x1086689)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/gin.go:555 (0x108666f)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
C:/Users/NK086843/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/gin.go:511 (0x1086112)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2867 (0xe76e29)
        serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1932 (0xe721ac)
        (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371 (0xc3d900)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
←[0m
[GIN] 2022/05/09 - 14:08:00 |←[97;41m 500 ←[0m|     19.7185ms |       127.0.0.1 |←[97;42m PATCH   ←[0m "/books/2"
```

**GO Models**

```
func UpdateBook(c *gin.Context) {
    // Get model if exist
    var book models.Book
    if err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", c.Param("id")).First(&book).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Record not found!"})
        return
    }

    // Validate input
    var input UpdateBookInput
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    models.DB.Model(&book).Updates(input)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": book})
}
```

**UpdateBookInput Struct**

```
type UpdateBookInput struct {
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
}
```

**main.go**

```
func main() {

    router := gin.Default()

    models.ConnectDatabase()

    router.GET("/books", controllers.FetchBooks)
    router.GET("/books/:id", controllers.FindBookByID)
    router.GET("/books/title/:title", controllers.FindBookByTitle)
    router.GET("/books/author/:author", controllers.FindBookByAuthor)

    router.POST("/books", controllers.CreateBook)

    router.PATCH("/books/:id", controllers.UpdateBook)

    router.DELETE("/books/:id", controllers.RemoveBook)

    router.Run()
}
```

**Request URL and Body**
URL

```
PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8080/books/2
```

BODY

```
{
    "title": "Breaking Dawn",
}
```

**Schema/Model**

```
package models

type Book struct {
    ID     uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
}
```

Comment: I have also tried using maps instead of struct in the Updates param but when only few columns are given in the JSON, the rest of columns are updated as empty once the Update Query is processed in GORM.

Comment: @TheFool I have added the schema for the DB in the question above.

Comment: what does the `UpdateBookInput` struct look like?

Comment: @TheFool I created the table with GORM and I am using mysql database.

Comment: @EminLaletovic I added the struct structure in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the JSON data contains an ID field which is of type string, because the only uint field is ID here. Either gorm is behaving weird with Updates or its something like this.

Make sure the input is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the UpdateBookInput object directly, convert it to a `models.Book` object.

Comment: I get an InvalidConversion Error when I do that.

Comment: Is to you create a function that convert the object to the correct one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).